# Error in routes after switching to rails 3.1 from rails 3.0.9

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model "Company" that has :id, :name and sometimes :domain, and there're such routes: if a company has :domain then it's /companies/:domain, otherwise it's /companies/:id
There're such routes in my routes.rb file:

```
get "/companies/:id(.:format)", :controller => "companies", :action => "show", :as => "company", :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }
get "/companies/:domain(.:format)", :controller => "companies", :action => "show", :as => "company"
```

And there's a helper method for generating routes in companies_helper.rb:

```
def company_c_path(c)
  company_path(c.domain.present? ? c.domain : c.id)
end
```

It works in rails 3.0.9 (with mysql 0.2.7) but doesn't in rails 3.1.0 (with mysql >= 0.3). The last case problem is

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies"}
```

To be more specific, let's consider company with :id=1 and :domain="lala". Error appears when we send request to /companies/1. Rails successfully parsers this request (params = {:id=>1}),  then in my view there's

```
<%= link_to @company.name, company_c_path(@company) %>
```

And here it seems rails can't find company_path method. But if we send /companies/lala, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the full options unless you use a resource.

```
def company_c_path(c)
  company_path(c.domain.present? ? { :domain => c.domain } : { :id => c.id })
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I added this, but nothing changes. rails 3.0.9 works and rails 3.1.0 doesn't on the /companies/1 path. Both works with /companies/lala path.

Comment: Try the method company_path(:id => 10) in the console and see if it works. If it does, the error is elsewhere.